# Find the image of a set under the complex exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

How can I find the image of the set {z in C: Re(z)<0, |Im(z)|<π} under the exponential function?
It is known that the exponential function maps {x+iy:|y|<π} onto {z:-π< arg(z)< π}, but how can I apply this result in this problem?

Comment: Try to express $\exp(x+iy)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. Note that there's a section called "Avoid "no-clue" questions", so you may want to rework your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z\in\Omega$, we may write it as $z=x+iy$, where $x<0,-\pi<y<\pi$.

As a simple try you can consider the image of $z=iy$, though it is not our goal. Notice that
$$|e^z|=|e^{iy}|=1$$
for $-\pi<y<\pi.$ This is actually the unit circle without the point $-1$ (since $-1$ is for $y=\pi$ or $-\pi$). Hence, in general,
$$|e^z|=|e^{x+iy}|=|e^x|<1$$
since $x<0$. The image will become the open unit disc without the line segment $(-1,0].$ In other words, it is $U\setminus(-1,0]$, where $U$ is the open unit disc.